# Enable clean urls drupal 7.56 / nginx - check failed

Tags: uri

I have an issue with the clean urls check. When I test there is an error in the Nginx log:

```
2017/10/06 09:49:01 [error] 468#468: *199 open() 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/drupal-7/admin/config/search/clean-urls/check" failed
 (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.254, server: localhost,
 request: "GET /drupal-7/admin/config/search/clean-urls/check HTTP/1.0",
 host: "localhost".
```

I don't know if it is a nginx problem or a Drupal problem.

update : i change some things in the nginx.conf now i have an error in the log of nginx :
2017/10/14 21:55:08 [error] 4804#4804: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/drupal-7/" is forbidden, client: 192.168.1.254, server: localhost, request: "GET /drupal-7/?q=admin/config/search/clean-urls HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost".
Here is my nginx.conf :

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;
# set client body size to 200M #
client_max_body_size 200M;


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name toniozz75.fr;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;


location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}


location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
         root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
         fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index  index.php;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
         include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some configuration for clean URLs. Try adding this snippet above the `location @rewrite` snippet.

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
 }
```